# How to manage subscribers in SFMC where subscriberkey is going to change, impact on journeys and campaigns

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, subscriber, merge, subscriber-key

**Current subscriberKey:** In SFMC, we use a unique identifier "Customer_ID" as our SubsciberKey.

**Use-case:** There is a very small percentage of customers where "Customer_ID" may change (when certain contacts merges in the back-end processes / systems before SFMC)

**Impact**

- Today, if a customer becomes a subscriber in SFMC with SubscriberKey = 10101
- This customer enters a journey with decision split that uses contact model.
- Tomorrow, if the SubscriberKey in back-end for this customer changes to = 20202
- Then this customer will fail at decision split of the journey since contact model will have a record linked to ID 20202 (NOT 10101 anymore, going forward all updates will be linked with the new id - i.e. SubscriberKey).

**Question** I understand there is no way to merge subscribers or update subscriberkey in SFMC (that can only be done with the migration project with Salesforce team).

Any recommendation on how we can make sure subcriber communication in journeys are not impacted if subscriberKey changes for the customer? There could be critical emails in journey that customer may miss due to this.

Comment: Subscriber Key changes outside of SFMC don't cause _changes_ in SFMC.  You're introducing a new subscriber. The real question is: How should you deal with multiple records for a single email address?

Comment: Hi @AdamSpriggs You are absolutely right, this merge contact use-case outside SFMC will end up creating multiple records in SFMC. In this case, 10101 will technically becomes obsolete and 20202 will be the new one. There are 2 impacts: **ONE** Somehow maintaining the old subscriberkey value IF contact is in the journey because if journey includes decision splits and after the merge new database updates are going to record with ID 20202, the old ID 10101 within an active journey can fail at decision split (so, somehow we will need to continue to push updates to profile of ID 10101 and ID 20202

Comment: **TWO** When customers exit the journey then  compare with a contact merge log and delete the old subscriber.

Comment: So, I have some questions like - **(1)** Is there any "better" alternative to deal with the subscribers apart from the approach I just shared above (somehow maintaining the old subkey value IF a contact is in a journey) then deleting it? **(2)** Is deleting right after the journey is the right call? **(3)** Potential impact is losing tracking history of old ID subscriber  **(4)** just curious, how would you handle this use-case? I am interested in learning new ways / open to ideas.